# Beamer: Weird content of \printbibliography

Tags: beamer, biblatex

The following MWE produces a weird content of the printed bibliography and uses the wrong frame title.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@article{barzel2007konnen,
  title={Wie k{\"o}nnen Lehramtsstudierende auf den Einsatz von Rechnern 
im Mathematikunterricht vorbereitet werden?},
  author={Barzel, B{\"a}rbel},
  journal={Beitr{\"a}ge zum Mathematikunterricht 2007, 41. Jahrestagung der Gesellschaft f{\"u}r Didaktik der Mathematik vom 25.3. bis 30.3. 2007 in Berlin},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Gesellschaft f{\"u}r Didaktik der Mathematik}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\frametitle{Gliederung}\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,hideothersubsections]}}

\begin{document}
\section{Literatur}
\nocite{barzel2007konnen}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]{Literatur}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As shown below, the first frame is correctly placed with the toc. But the second frame has the wrong section title (should be "Literatur I" instead of "Gliederung I") and the space between the two horizontal rules should not be there.

[image: Wrong output]

If I comment out the `\AtBeginSection`, the bibliography is correctly rendered (see below), but the desired toc at the start of each section is missing - because i commented it out.

[image: Almost right output]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem occurs because `\printbibliography` creates a new (unnumbered) section inside your frame -- to disable this, use `\printbibliography[heading=none]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@article{barzel2007konnen,
  title={Wie k{\"o}nnen Lehramtsstudierende auf den Einsatz von Rechnern 
im Mathematikunterricht vorbereitet werden?},
  author={Barzel, B{\"a}rbel},
  journal={Beitr{\"a}ge zum Mathematikunterricht 2007, 41. Jahrestagung der Gesellschaft f{\"u}r Didaktik der Mathematik vom 25.3. bis 30.3. 2007 in Berlin},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Gesellschaft f{\"u}r Didaktik der Mathematik}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\frametitle{Gliederung}\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,hideothersubsections]}}

\begin{document}
\section{Literatur}
\nocite{barzel2007konnen}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]{Literatur}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```