# Beamer: Bibliography and AtBeginSection

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I want to show the bibliography (`\printbibliography`) at the end of the presentation and the ToC at the beginning of every section (`\AtBeginSection{...}`). Both parts work separately, but not combined.

How to reproduce:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\references.bib}
@misc{reference,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2018},
  title = {Some Title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\references.bib}

% I can either do this...
\AtBeginSection{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  This is some random text.
\end{frame}

\section{Section B}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  This is some more random text.\cite{reference}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{References}
  % ... or this
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Occured errors:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.76 \end{frame}
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.76 \end{frame}
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endframe ->\egroup 
                    \begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame}
l.76 \end{frame}
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> }

l.76 \end{frame}
```

Comment: With `\printbibliography[heading=none]` (as suggested in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371416/123129)) it works.